# General Solution of Linear Diophantine Equation with 2 and more than 2 variable

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers, linear-diophantine-equations

We know the theorem of linear diophantine equation from Bezout's identity that the solution is in ordered pair form:

$\left(x + m \dfrac{b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}\,,\,y-m \dfrac{a}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}\right)$

For all integers $m$

Then, what is the general integer solutions for a linear diophantine equation with 3 or more than 3 variables?

Comment: Suggest you state what equation your pairs are a solution of.

Comment: Says $ax+by+cz=d$

Comment: Yes, but better to put that in question, say above solution.

Comment: Anyway i got the answer already. Thanks